# CSS: border wave at the edges of the block

Tags: html, css, border

My task is to make a div block with a border in the form of a wave, as in the picture.

[image]

Somewhere on the web, I found a perfectly suitable example for me. I added 4 children to the main div block for each side.

However, if the lower wave got up perfectly, then nothing comes out with the upper and even more lateral ones.

```css
.menu {
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    padding: 14px;
    background-color: #63B32F;
    
    font-size:16px;
    color:#fff;
    text-align: center;
}

.topwave::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    height: 10px;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    background-image:
        radial-gradient(circle at 10px -5px, transparent 12px, #fff 13px);
}

.topwave::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    height: 12px;
    background-size: 40px 20px;
    background-image:
        radial-gradient(circle at 10px 13px, #fff 12px, transparent 13px);
}

.bottomwave::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    height: 10px;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    background-image:
        radial-gradient(circle at 10px -5px, transparent 12px, #fff 13px);
}

.bottomwave::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    height: 12px;
    background-size: 40px 20px;
    background-image:
        radial-gradient(circle at 10px 13px, #fff 12px, transparent 13px);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    <div class="topwave"></div>
    <div class="bottomwave"></div>
    <div class="leftwave"></div>
    <div class="rightwave"></div>
    <div class="content">Some content</div>
</div>
```

For the top I also tried `transform: rotate(180deg);`. It seems to work out, but it doesn't seem to be the best solution.

```css
.menu {
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    height:80px;
    padding: 14px;
    background-color: #63B32F;
    
    font-size:16px;
    color:#fff;
    text-align: center;
}

.topwave {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.topwave::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: -10px;
    top: 4px;
    right: -10px;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    height: 10px;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 10px -3px, transparent 12px, #fff 13px);
}

.topwave::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: -10px;
    top: 4px;
    right: -10px;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    height: 12px;
    background-size: 40px 20px;
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 10px 13px, #fff 12px, transparent 13px);
}

.bottomwave::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    height: 10px;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    background-image:
        radial-gradient(circle at 10px -5px, transparent 12px, #fff 13px);
}

.bottomwave::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    height: 12px;
    background-size: 40px 20px;
    background-image:
        radial-gradient(circle at 10px 13px, #fff 12px, transparent 13px);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    <div class="topwave"></div>
    <div class="bottomwave"></div>
    <div class="leftwave"></div>
    <div class="rightwave"></div>
    <div class="content">Some content</div>
</div>
```